# SSRS Report - Get number of rows in a grouped column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Thank you in advance for all of your help!

I am trying to determine how to get a count of the number of values in the first column of a report where I have it grouped on a number. So for example if I had the table below I would want to have an output of 5 at the bottom of the first column. I have tried multiple things but my attempts either fail or I get the number of rows within each group or the total number of rows in the table.

```
+----------+---------+-------+------+
| Number   | Order   | Month | Year |
+----------+---------+-------+------+
| 142010   | 1800053 | 1     | 2018 |
+          +---------+-------+------+
|          | 1800045 | 4     | 2018 |
+----------+---------+-------+------+
| 1622220  | 1700021 | 10    | 2017 |
+----------+---------+-------+------+
| 20101040 | 1600065 | 4     | 2016 |
+          +---------+-------+------+
|          | 1400056 | 8     | 2014 |
+----------+---------+-------+------+
| 21968145 | 1800004 | 4     | 2018 |
+----------+---------+-------+------+
| 4893154  | 1400021 | 4     | 2014 |
+          +---------+-------+------+
|          | 1200047 | 6     | 2012 |
+          +---------+-------+------+
|          | 1200056 | 1     | 2012 |
+----------+---------+-------+------+
| Total: 5 |         |       |      |
+----------+---------+-------+------+
```

I apologize if this has been asked before, I tried searching but could not find a similar question. Any advice would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try the expression - `=CoutRows("YourGroupName")` ... You can also do it with other `COUNT()` expressions. `=CountDistinct(Fields!Number.Value, "YourGroupName")`

Comment: Thank you for your help. These are expressions that I have tried so I think my issue is I am not sure where to place it in my report. I can't seem to get any count to work where I reference my group name. I ended up just taking a count of numbers in each group, which is always 1, and then taking the sum of this value. It is a work around that seems really off but at least gives me the final result I need. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Right click the cell and pick Add Total. Add expression =COUNT(Fields!order.Value)

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to COUNTDISTINCT and that worked. Thank you!